# Alt+Left Click doesn't select Loops on sharp edges (<90°)

Tags: modeling, select

If I Alt+Left Click on any loops, that are not along sharp edges, i don't have this issue. Selecting the outer edge of a singular plane works fine aswell. It's only on models like the one that's shown in the image.

The same thing happens in vertext select mode.

How can I properly select these edges without clicking them indicidually or by ctrl+left click?

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Comment: This is the same post as mine I posted today. Are we sure this is true? Cause this worked for me! Check my post with pictures:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/289467/alt-mouse-click-not-selecting-edges-but-selecting-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no loop in your image. You misunderstand what a loop is. See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html

That's a loop:
[image]

You can see it ends when there are no more edge intersections where there are 4 faces around the vertex of intersection. Kind of hard to explain, but when you get it, it's very intuitive.

One more example:

[image]

The loop ends at the corner in the first one, but the second one has edges marked in red, so the loop continues.

The topology must be a grid of faces and then the edges defining the grid are loops, but only the topology is important here, it can be in any shape or form in 3d space.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth explanation! I was thinking something along those lines(ha!) but I wasn't sure. Have a great Day.